# How to deal with ResolutionException?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-11, java-module

I'm trying to use Java Modules in my Spring Boot project and I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules jsr305 and java.annotation export package javax.annotation to module org.jvnet.staxex
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JDK8 to run this code.
It seems to be a compatability [issue](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/1435)

**Edit:**

The root cause is that this package has been removed. (https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) from the standard JVM installation after java 8.

Some of the dependencies in your code depends on it, therefore, there is a launch probelem. It comes from this dependency `org.jvnet.staxex`. Its used for XML parsing. Swapping it out for another package, which does not have this dependency is likely to be time consuming if you have a large XML-related code base.

What might work is trying to manually add the dependency which provides these classes. Try adding [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305) to your dependencies

Also, this [blog post](https://nipafx.dev/jsr-305-java-9/) might help

Comment: thanks, but I wouldn't like to downgrade from JDK11. Is there any other option?

Comment: Maybe try upgrading instead, this issue might be fixed in later versions.

Comment: what's the root cause of this?

Comment: See EDIT to the main answer

Comment: JSR 305 has not been removed, it never was included in Java. And a removal can not be “the root cause” when the error message clearly say that this module is present in this environment. In fact, it says that there are *two* packages of that name, not that it was missing.